# Chrome and Opera placeholder

Tags: html, google-chrome, opera

In chrome I had this CSS :

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder{color:blue;}
input:-moz-placeholder{color:blue;}
```

Idecided to optimize it to:

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder, input:-moz-placeholder{color:blue;}
```

And the placeholder disappered! Why is this happenning - some kind of bug or what?

And the other problem is Opera:
['placeholder' in document.createElement('input')](http://diveintohtml5.info/everything.html#placeholder) returns true. So this means that it is available. But it is not showing.

The rest of the CSS for the input(if needed):

```
input[type=text]{
    color: blue;
    height: 24px; width: 75px;
    padding-left: 24px;
    outline: none;
    background-color: #ABABAB;
    background-image: url('searchtool-1.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
       -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 6px;
       -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 6px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
}
```

Edit: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZPPXD/)

Comment: I can see a placeholder in Opera just fine here: `data:text/html,<!doctype><input placeholder="placeholder">`

Comment: I can see placeholder in Opera in your fiddle demo too. (but of course without blue color)

Comment: @alexander farkas I saw it too, when I removed the background color. But why the blue color is not applied to the placeholder`s text?

Comment: The HTML spec does only specify HTML and DOM APIs not CSS (big problem). The CSS has no module, which defines a pseudoelement selector for placeholder and Opera has not implemented this. The -moz, -webkit and -ms selectors are non-standard.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While you can mix unknown CSS properties, you can not mix different unknown CSS selectors. If a browser sees an unknown selector, it will ignore the hole block.

This is by CSS specification.

You should also use: :-ms-input-placeholder for IE10.

Opera should support the placeholder in input elements. Ca you make a fiddle?

Comment: what's the setting for opera?